# Select XML element based on value of sibling

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Using Linq to XML and the example XML document below, how would I get the value of "itemType" where the "itemColor" is blue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<items>
    <item>
         <itemName>my item name</itemName>
         <itemType>spoon</itemType>
         <itemColor>red</itemColor>
    </item>
    <item>
         <itemName>your item name</itemName>
         <itemType>fork</itemType>
         <itemColor>blue</itemColor>
    </item>
 </items>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var itemType = xdoc.Root.Elements("item")
                   .Where(i => (string)i.Element("itemColor") == "blue")
                   .Select(i => (string)i.Element("itemType"))
                   .FirstOrDefault();
// returns "fork"
```

Another option is single line with XPath:

```
var type = (string)xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//item[itemColor='blue']/itemType");
```

**BTW** for using XPath extensions of XDocument you should use *System.Xml.XPath* namespace.

Comment: Hmm, using the first example I am getting an error of "system.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Ling.XElement does not contain a definition for "Where" and no extion method "Where' accepting a first argument of type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>" could be found.

Comment: @user2121236 make sure you have `using System.Linq` at the top of file

Comment: That was it.   I had `using System.Xml.Linq;` but not `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("../../sample.xml");
var elements = from item in doc.Descendants("items").Descendants("item")
               where item.Element("itemColor").Value == "blue"
               select item.Element("itemType").Value;
```

By the way: This is **not** LINQ to SQL (where would SQL come from in this example) but [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/bb387098.aspx)